# QT GroupBox stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, stylesheet

I have a question regarding the QGroupBox stylesheet. I want a custom stylesheet for QGroupBox that looks similar to the image below:

[image]

Can you please tell me how to look "Device Info" Style with white background?

Answer (score 2):

Use `setStyleSheet` function to set any style for any state programmatically.

For your case, first obtain the `QGroupBox` object and let us assume "pGroupBox".
As you need title's back ground color to be white, you can set it as shown below.

```
pGroupBox->setStyleSheet("::title{background-color:white}");
```

Almost you can style anything check below link:
(you can set based on different psuedo states for different sub controls.)

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color here

```
 QGroupBox {
 background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                   stop: 0 #E0E0E0, stop: 1 #FFFFFF);
 border: 2px solid gray;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-top: 1ex; /* leave space at the top for the title */
}
```

specify the color whatever you want at the place of red.

Look at the [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html).

Comment: i don't want for QPushButton. I want for QGroupBox the "Device Info" seen in the image. How to set the background of "Device Info" text seen in the image. How to change the background through CSS ?

Comment: same like pushbutton you can do with groupbox. search qgroupbox in specified link for more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to change style for QGroupBox::title subcontrol. http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-e7d01e98-168f-4c8a-ac7f-77233a406ba4